# New hard drive accessible to everyone

Tags: permissions, ext4

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 desktop

The only way I've found out how to gain access to a second hard drive through nautilus is to re-install Ubuntu while the hard drive is in the computer. Then, when I go to look at the "500 GB Volume", I can actually go in and create folders and such.

After that, I added my linux cpu to a Windows domain and now when I try accessing the HD, I'm prompted for the old *local* users' password. I have tried many different suggestions found online about how to just set the security to world readable, but now I would like to just start over (without having to re-install Ubuntu).

In another attempt (re-install of Ubuntu), I deleted the original user that was created upon installation, so when I tried accessing the HD the second time it asked for the "root" password, of which, when I tried using the password of the deleted user, it didn't work of course. So, I set a root password but now I'm back to square one again. A 500 GB hard drive that I can't access.

Can someone explain how to format with ext4 and set permissions to world readable on a newly added internal hard drive?? I don't understand permissions too much and so I'm not sure where to set the permissions. On /dev/sdb1 or /media/user/LONG-UGLY-UUID-NAME.

**chmod -R 777 /pathto...?**

**chown -R domainUID:domainGUI /pathto....?**

Thanks!

Comment: Auto-mounting and file access permissions are two unrelated issues. Can you please move one of them to a new question?

Comment: Ok, removed the trailing question on how to auto-mount the HD

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you read about [*nix modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_%28Unix%29) since you will likely encounter them again and again.

## [Changing access rights](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/chmod.1.html)

You can change a file or directory to be world (=everybody) readable with:

```sh
chmod a+rX [PATH...]
```

- `a` means to apply the change for all classes (owner, group, and world).
- `+` means to grant additional access rights.
- `r` means the right to read.
- `X` means the right to execute (regular file) or traverse (directory), if at least one class already has execution/traversal access. It's important to use `X` (capital letter) instead of `x` because otherwise all files would be flagged executable, which is at best confusing and at worst a security problem.

If you're not the file owner you need to acquire superuser privileges first by prepending `sudo` to that command. To change the permission of a directory tree recursively, add the `-R` switch as the first argument.

## [Changing ownership](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/chown.1.html)

If you want your main user account to own the file system root (e. g. because you want to use it for documents, multimedia or other non-system files), it would be more elegant to hand over the ownership to it:

```sh
sudo chown [-R] "$USER:" [PATH...]
```

This will change the ownership over `[PATH...]` to user `$USER` (which is usually the name of the user currently logged in) and the group ownership to the default login group of that user. Again `-R` applies the changes recursively.